# Prediction interval method explanation

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

For making prediction intervals, the book (*Applied statistics and probability for engineers by montgomery and runger 5th edition*) creates a new random variable called prediction error and based on that (after translation and scaling to standard $T$) it creates a PI for $X_{n+1}$. My question is this:
Why not use $\overline{X}$ as an estimate for mean of $X_{n+1}$ and use sample standard dev as estimate for std of $X_{n+1}$ and basically create a PI based on that like we do for confidence interval. Why use prediction error?

What is wrong with my method?

Thank you

[image: part1 of the method]

[image: part2 of the method]

Comment: $\overline X$ is a random variable by itself, so its distribution should be taken into account because you may be way off with your prediction not because $X_{n+1}$ is far from the true mean, but because $\overline X$ is a poor estimate for the true mean. That's the key point. The rest is just computation and some fancy terminology.

Comment: Hi @fedja, thanks for the comment. If we write it like this: https://ibb.co/cxDpTWL , aren't we taking into account X¯ ?

Comment: We don't. In that way we pretend that $\overline X$ is the true mean. The variance of the difference $X_{n+1}-\overline X$ is *not* just the variance of $X_{n+1}$ (i.e., not $\sigma^2$) but the sum of the variances of $X_{n+1}$ and $\overline X$, which adds an extra $\sigma^2/n$ and that is the key point.

Comment: thank you for your help.